# Why does my c++ service have 21 heaps

Tags: c++, mysql, odbc, c++builder

My 32-bit C++ service has 5 heaps (none created by the service code itself) when run in a WIN2012 R2 virtual machine using 1 CPU. When run in a standalone machine with the same OS but with 8 CPUs it has 21 heaps. How can this be possible?
The service runs 8 threads that talk to a MySQL database through ODBC.

Comment: The first question is why you care, and the second is where you're finding out this information. Usually heaps are created by the allocation library in an efficient enough way, and when multiple threads are involved it might be more efficient to have more than to deal with thread locking.

Comment: I have a trace utility in the service that has a heap listing command to be able to find memory leaks. It says 21 heaps and i got the same result running VMMap. Only 3 of the heaps show some activity of significance at all. I want to know if these heaps are created without the service beeing aware of it so that errors can occur when trying to use the heap.

Comment: It's really rare to be concerned about the inner workings of the memory management system. If there's leaks, find the leaks. If the allocator is doing things you don't understand, read up on how the allocator works.